# JTable Focus Related Query?

Tags: java, jtable

In Jtable when Tab key is pressed the focus shifts to the next cell of the table. If have to restrict the movement, is there any possible way of doing it....

Thank You in advance....

Comment: So you want pressing the TAB key not to shit the focus?

Comment: Yes, i have TextFeild, while validation , it turns red, when focus goes to underneath cell, the red colour is lost, so trying to restrict the movement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JTable table = ...;
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0), "none");
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK), "none");
```

Comment: Thank You, can this be Done, just out of curiosity, can focus movement be only row oriented, i.e, if focus reaches end of row(0), it should not be enter row(1).... Thank you in advance....

Comment: you can do it yourself by adding a keylistener to your table and on the KeyTyped move to where you want or by replacing the default tab/arrow down arrouw up actions
getTable().getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "doMyArrowDown");
getTable().getActionMap().put("doMyArrowDown", new ArrowDownAction());

Answer (score 1):

> if focus reaches end of row(0), it should not be enter row

You need to replace the default left/right Action with a custom Action of your own.

You can choose to write your own Action. It would not be that difficult. All you would need to do is invoke changeSelection(...) method of the table with the next column number.

Or [Table Tabbing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/table-tabbing/) show how you can reuse the existing Action. This is probably not required for this requiement, but it may be helpful for more complex requirements.